I want to export a model along with its textures and animations
I want to export the model such that it can be used in powerpoint.
Is it even possible to do?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

i suppose it does.. thanks for answering!

If you want textures and animations, I would suggest exporting in .gltf format with .glb selected. I think GLTF (or GLB which includes textures and animations) can be embedded in powerpoint relatively easily as well. - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzDM42PdqZk
